# Calculating growth factor in python

Tags: python, group-by

I have the following dataframe

```
Date           Country  Sales
01/02/20        France   1000
01/02/20        Germany  1000
02/02/20        France   2000
02/02/20        Germany  3000
03/02/20        France   4500
03/02/20        Germany  5000
```

I want to calculate the growth factor by country for each day. For example the growth factor for Germany on 02/02/20 = 3000/1000 & on 03/02/2020 should be 5000/3000. Not looking for a percentage change.

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is the resultant factor for example Germany on 02/02/20 =3 (3000/1000)

Comment: What about the growth factor of germany on 01/02/20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
['01/02/20',        'France '  ,1000],
['01/02/20',        'Germany'  ,1000],
['02/02/20',        'France '  ,2000],
['02/02/20',        'Germany'  ,3000],
['03/02/20',        'France '  ,4500],
['03/02/20',        'Germany'  ,5000]
], columns=['Date', 'Country', 'Sales'])
df['Diff'] = df.groupby(['Country']).diff()
df['Growth'] = df.eval('Sales/(Sales - Diff)')
print(df)
```

Another alternative is as above.

```
       Date  Country  Sales    Diff    Growth
0  01/02/20  France    1000     NaN       NaN
1  01/02/20  Germany   1000     NaN       NaN
2  02/02/20  France    2000  1000.0  2.000000
3  02/02/20  Germany   3000  2000.0  3.000000
4  03/02/20  France    4500  2500.0  2.250000
5  03/02/20  Germany   5000  2000.0  1.666667
```

Answer (score 0):

Begin by sorting by country: `df = df.sort_values(['Country'])`

Then set up a filter which only returns true when an index is the same as the previous (i.e. they are of the same country):
`filter = df['Country'] == df['Country'].shift(1)`

Now calculate the fractional change on the last point where the above filter is true:

`df['Growth']  = df['Sales'].where(filter)/df['Sales'].shift(1)`

Finally resort by index:

`df = df.sort_index()`

Results in:

```
       Date  Country  Sales     Growth
0  01/02/20   France   1000         NaN
1  01/02/20  Germany   1000         NaN
2  02/02/20   France   2000    2.000000
3  02/02/20  Germany   3000    3.000000
4  03/02/20   France   4500    2.250000
5  03/02/20  Germany   5000    1.666667
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df["Growth Factor"] = df.groupby(
    "Country")["Sales"].transform(lambda g: g / g.shift())
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
       Date  Country  Sales  Growth Factor
0  01/02/20   France   1000            NaN
1  01/02/20  Germany   1000            NaN
2  02/02/20   France   2000       2.000000
3  02/02/20  Germany   3000       3.000000
4  03/02/20   France   4500       2.250000
5  03/02/20  Germany   5000       1.666667
```